# Is it possible to update a databinding source value with the set TargetNullValue in case it is 'null'?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

Just out of interest....

In case I have a ViewModel with an uninitialized string, which is bound to a Textbox, I can use `TargetNullValue` to display a default value. 
However, I was wondering if I can use the same value to update the string in case it is `null`?

Basically instead of

```
    set
    {
        if(value != null) text = value;
        else value = "defaultstring";
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
```

just do the same thing from the databinding using `TargetNullValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the getter as well as the data binding will use the get():

```
    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (text== null)
                return "default value";
            else
                return this.text;
        }
        set { this.text= value; }

    }
```

However, if you want to do it in Pure XAML you can use a DataTrigger for this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}">
   <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock }">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyText}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="DefaultValue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Of course I can, but the question remains, if I could do the same thing from the xaml /view using just databinding. It is more of a rhetorical question ;)

Comment: mhh.. you could use a ValueConverter...but I guess that is not the answer you a looking for. In this case, the answer is NO you cannot do it in pure XAML only in less convenient ways like a ValueConverter or a DataTrigger that replaces the text if value is null

Comment: i added the pure XAML variant with a `DataTrigger`

Comment: Ah yes, data trigger....probably would be the way to go in such a case. Thanks! Will mark the answer as soon as it let's me

Comment: Glad i could help :) Please mark it as answer if it helped you so others can find it as well